# ComboBox of Types with a ValueConverter and Custom Attributes

Tags: wpf, binding, types, ivalueconverter

I'm using MVVM, in case it makes a difference.

My *MainWindowViewModel* has two DependencyProperties, **TheList**, and **TheSelectedItem**. **TheList** is a *List<Type>*, **TheSelectedItem** is a *Type*.

The MainWindow has a *ComboBox*. When the *MainWindowViewModel* loads it grabs a list of all the classes in the assembly that implement *IMyInterface* and sets **TheList** to this.

Each of these classes has a custom attribute applied called *DisplayName*, which has one parameter, that will be used to show a user-friendly name for the class instead of the name the application knows about for the class.

I've also got a *ValueConverter* for the express purpose of converting these types into the display names.

```
    public class TypeToDisplayName : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType.Name == "IEnumerable")
            {
                List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
                if (value is List<Type>)
                {
                    foreach (Type t in value as List<Type>)
                    {
                        returnList.Add(ReflectionHelper.GetDisplayName(t));
                    }
                }

                return returnList;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return typeof(BasicTemplate);
        }
    }
```

So, what I wind up with is a *ComboBox* with a list of names in it that the user should be able to understand. Awesome! This is just what I want!

Next step: I bind the SelectedItem property of my *ComboBox* to my **TheSelectedItem** property in my ViewModel.

Here's the problem: When I make a selection, I get a little red box around my ComboBox and the **TheSelectedItem** property on my ViewModel never gets set.

I'm pretty sure it's because of a type mismatch (the items in the ComboBox appear to be strings now, and **TheSelectedItem** is of type *Type*--also, when I change **TheSelectedItem** to a *string* instead of a *Type*, it works). But I don't know where I need to start coding to convert the (hopefully unique) DisplayName that's in the ComboBox back to a Type object.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm pretty stumped on this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you use that Converter on the ItemsSource for the ComboBox? In that case I think you can let the ItemsSource be like it is and instead just Convert each type when they are presented like this.

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=typeName, Converter={StaticResource TypeToDisplayNameConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And then just convert each type in the Converter.

```
public class TypeToDisplayNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type t = (Type)value;
        return ReflectionHelper.GetDisplayName(t);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spot on! I should have known I was doing something dumb when the converter was converting the entire collection in one go. Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony Using a converter to display a string is not needed...set the DisplayMemberPath to be DisplayName and be done with it. Remove your converter all together.

Comment: ComboBox's ItemsSource is a List of Types. Type doesn't have a Property called DisplayName.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) set to true on the `ComboBox`. Check [this](http://japikse.blogspot.com/2008/10/wpf-combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue.html) out...

Comment: I just gave that a try. Unfortunately it didn't get me anywhere. Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: Can you edit question and post your bindings please...you don't the converter to go back to the type like you are thinking...